# can we Fetching multiple MicroStrategy objects at once with filtering capability like Query Builder?

Tags: query-builder, microstrategy

In General, I used to parse `MicroStrategy Document ID` for getting the list of Documents in the corresponding Id, so

- How can I use any Query instead of parsing ID?
- I sit possible in Microstrategy?
- If yes can someone suggest me the approach?

Comment: Could you explain better what is your goal? Are you trying to obtain a list of the MicroStrategy documents in a specific folder?

Comment: @mucio
We have installed Microstrategy v10.9.0 30 days trail version. We are working on REST API's.

Is there any such REST API which can get all the micro-strategy objects ID's such as report ID, cube ID, document ID, dossier ID, data source ID in order to use the object's REST API. Please let us know if we have any such REST API in trail version.

 

Currently we have to manually pass specific report ID (hardcode valule) , specific cube ID (hardcode value) and so on to get the metadata of the object. So is this it limitation of due to the trail version of the tool?

Comment: Did you try the the `folder` and `search` [APIs](https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api-docs/index.html#/)? Not sure if they are available also in version 10.9

Comment: Which API are you using to get object metadata?